# Sorting a table based on which header cell was clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

If I have the following:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th><a href="Index.cfm?Sort=0">First</a></th>
<th><a href="Index.cfm?Sort=1">Second</a></th>
<th><a href="Index.cfm?Sort=2">Third</a></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>A</td>
<td class="num">123</td>
<td><input name="XYZ"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Q: How do I sort the table body based upon which table header cell was clicked?

```
<script>
$('th a').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this).closest('th');
    console.log($this.index());
    return false;
});
</script>
```

(I made each of the table header cells hyperlinks so that if the user has JavaScript turned off, it will follow the link and be sorted on the server side).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function OrderBy(a,b,n) {
    if (n) return a-b;
    if (a < b) return -1;
    if (a > b) return 1;
    return 0;
}
$('th a').click(function() {
    var $th = $(this).closest('th');
    $th.toggleClass('selected');
    var isSelected = $th.hasClass('selected');
    var isInput= $th.hasClass('input');
    var column = $th.index();
    var $table = $th.closest('table');
    var isNum= $table.find('tbody > tr').children('td').eq(column).hasClass('num');
    var rows = $table.find('tbody > tr').get();
    rows.sort(function(rowA,rowB) {
        if (isInput) {
            var keyA = $(rowA).children('td').eq(column).children('input').val().toUpperCase();
            var keyB = $(rowB).children('td').eq(column).children('input').val().toUpperCase();
        } else {
            var keyA = $(rowA).children('td').eq(column).text().toUpperCase();
            var keyB = $(rowB).children('td').eq(column).text().toUpperCase();
        }
        if (isSelected) return OrderBy(keyA,keyB,isNum);
        return OrderBy(keyB,keyA,isNum);
    });
    $.each(rows, function(index,row) {
        $table.children('tbody').append(row);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You might be interested in [jQuery Plugin: Tablesorter](https://plugins.jquery.com/tablesorter/) or any [any other table sort plugin](http://www.google.pl/search?hl=pl&q=jquery+table+sort&btnG=Szukaj+w+Google&lr=).

Comment: Exactly. Why roll your own when there are loads out there?

Comment: Yeah, I looked at Tablesorter, but it isn't jQuery-UI compatible, so I ruled it out.

Answer (score 3):

```
/**
* This tidy function can sort your rows belonging to TBODY via an ID in your table
* The only thing it does is to sort a specific column in a ascending byte mode
* M.Rasch may 2010 xmlsoap.dk
*/
function sortColumn (id, colNo) {
  var zTemp = [];
  var rows = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr'); 

  for(ix=0;ix<rows.length;ix++){
    var column = rows[ix].getElementsByTagName('td')[colNo - 1]; // relative column offSet, one-based
    zTemp[ix] = [];                                              // prepare 2nd dimension  
    zTemp[ix][0] = column.innerHTML;                             // the "value" to sort ...
    zTemp[ix][1] = rows[ix];                                     // and here goes complete row   
  }
  zTemp.sort(function (elmA, elmB){
                    if (elmA[0] === elmB[0]) return 0;
                    return (elmA[0] < elmB[0]) ? -1 : 1;
                  }
  );
  for(ix=0;ix<rows.length;ix++){                                  // Remove row collection entirely
    var temp = rows[ix].parentNode;   
    temp.removeChild(rows[ix]);
  }
  var tBody = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
  for(ix=0;ix<zTemp.length;ix++){                                 // and re-insert them ...   
    tBody.appendChild(zTemp[ix][1]);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't as straight forward as it sounds.

First of all you need to decide if you will only sort alphanumeric or dates, numerics etc. Then you need to go through the data in each cell, add that to an array, sort the array, remove the tr's from the table, and re-add them in the correct order.

As it happens, there is a very good plugin that does it for you:

http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: My client has all kinds of business rules that he's going to throw at the sorting method, so I can't use a plug-in.  I have to write it myself.  I'm on page 160 of Learning jQuery 1.3, but I'm afraid that it's out of date since right away I saw they weren't using the .index property, which was introduced in 1.4.

Answer (score 1):

Another JQuery plugin: http://datatables.net/

I believe it is supposed to be JQuery UI compatible.

Edit:
Custom sorting functions are supported.
http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting

Answer (score 0):

```
function Ascending(a,b) {
    if (a < b) return -1;
    if (a > b) return 1;
    return 0;
}
$('th a').click(function() {
    var $th = $(this).closest('th');
    var column = $th.index(); // Todo: url.Sort
    var $table = $th.closest('table');
    var rows = $table.find('tbody > tr').get();
    rows.sort(function(rowA,rowB) {
        if (column == 2) {
            var keyA = $(rowA).children('td').eq(column).children('input').val().toUpperCase();
            var keyB = $(rowB).children('td').eq(column).children('input').val().toUpperCase();
        } else {
            var keyA = $(rowA).children('td').eq(column).text().toUpperCase();
            var keyB = $(rowB).children('td').eq(column).text().toUpperCase();
        }
        return Ascending(keyA,keyB);
    });
    $.each(rows, function(index,row) {
        $table.children('tbody').append(row);
    });
    return false;
});
```